# Not able to move file in the linux OS using java files.move

Tags: java, linux, file

I am trying to move files (**in linux OS**) by using java code  this happen when trying to move single file. Issue which looks to me is i guess similar to 
[java.nio.Files.move() - DirectoryNotEmptyException on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310799/java-nio-files-move-directorynotemptyexception-on-os-x)

If so how can we handle it . Shall it be done on linux level or java.

```
Files.move(src, dst, new CopyOption[] { StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING });
```

in this src folder is present in **projs/dd/output/TAR**
and dest folder is **config_files/billing/xml/workArea**

the error which comes is even though destination there is no file present nor folder in target:

```
WARNING: FAILED_TO$Failed to get MHS user handler
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: 
config_files/billing/xml/workArea/GBF_2017030001_000007540_00001_0000000004
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:491)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
        at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1347)
```

what i could see is both folders are on different FileSystem

by running `stat -c "%d" "${Folder}"`  on linux OS.

is this cause of exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Using nio Files.copy to Move Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137849/java-using-nio-files-copy-to-move-directory)

Comment: You cannot move a whole directory like this, unless it can be accomplished by a simple rename.  Copying the contents of a whole directory from one filesystem to another is not supported with a single `move` call...

Comment: i will edit the question. as it is movinf single file only but Error is misleading

Comment: We used java nio Files.move to move folder and it only works when moving in same file-system or when empty. In our case the filesystems are separate. So what I did was to add catch the exception and do copy+delete instead. I used apache file utils because they already have recursive copy and delete.